# Solution for : HTTP error 500.0 code 0x80070001

Tags: http, tomcat, iis

Hello guys I'm experiencing a problem after installing IIS and configure it with Tomcat9. what I get on the internet explorer is :

Detailed Error Information:

Module
IsapiFilterModule

Notification
AuthenticateRequest

Handler
StaticFile

Error Code
0x80070001

Requested URL
http://elpic840:80/pdweb-app/

Physical Path
D:\Tomcat9\webapps\pdweb-app\

Logon Method
Negotiate

Logon User
elpic_group\AC126310

Does anyone please now the solution for this ? I'm not sure but I think it's a problem of version for files jk2.properties, server.xml ... but I don't find them on internet to download them

Comment: In logs files I found this :  WARNING [Thread-5] org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.clearReferencesThreads The web application [pdweb-app] appears to have started a thread named [net.sf.ehcache.CacheManager@3772fcd8] but has failed to stop it. This is very likely to create a memory leak. Stack trace of thread:
27-Nov-2020 12:08:52.804 INFO [Thread-5] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.stop Stopping ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8080"]

Comment: 27-Nov-2020 12:08:52.835 INFO [Thread-5] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.stop Stopping ProtocolHandler ["ajp-nio-0.0.0.0-8009"]
27-Nov-2020 12:08:52.851 INFO [45] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.destroy Destroying ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8080"]
27-Nov-2020 12:08:52.854 INFO [45] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.destroy Destroying ProtocolHandler ["ajp-nio-0.0.0.0-8009"]

Comment: What project is pdweb-app?

Comment: it's a SAP project @DingPeng

Comment: According to your error message, this problem should be related to tomcat, I suspect this problem may be related to the configuration of tomcat.